# Loading a large binary file with kdb+ (Q)

Tags: kdb

I have a set of large files (around 2Gb).
When I attempt to load it (let's assume that correctly):

```
ctq_table:flip `QTIM`BID`OFR`QSEQ`BIDSIZE`QFRSIZ`OFRSIZ`MODE`EX`MMID!("ijjiiihcs";4 8 8 4 4 4 2 1 4) 1: `:/q/data/Q200405A.BIN
```

It gives back a `wsfull` error. Kdb+ as far as I know meant to be used for such tasks.

Is there a way to handle big files without running out of memory (like keeping on disk, even if it is slower)?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit kdb+?

Comment: Yes. That is the only version available here: https://kx.com/software-download.php

Comment: In this case you can't do much about it I am afraid. Due to a natural limitation of a 32-bit process it can't address more than 4GB (in reality it is just 2GB on Windows) and your dataset size probably hits that limit.

Comment: You can try loading your data in chunks using  three-item list as its second argument of a `1:` function: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/OneColon

Comment: The problem is, that I would like to run analysis on TB-s of data. According to the description, kdb+ is a suitable tool for handling big data. If it is not possible to run tasks on disk, and the max memory usage is 2GB, how is it even good for anything?

Comment: 32-bit version is free but not licensed for production use. There is a 64-bit version that is not limited by 2GB and can use all RAM you have in your server, but you will have to pay for it. And of course you can analyse terabytes of data even with 32-bit version, but in your original question you tried to load all your data in memory in one go, that will not work.

Comment: So is it possible to run queries on disk? (and the server decides what to actually load to the memory, and I just use the tables as symbols)

Comment: Yes, but you need to properly organise you data if you don't want kdb to load everything in memory. You can start from this link: http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/splayed_tables, then http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/partitioned_tables. By carefully choosing a partitioning method you can do a lot even with 32-bit version. Unfortunately, its license prohibits production use like I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor mentioned in the comments (and getting back on to the topic of the question) you can read the large binary file in chunks and write to disk one piece at a time. This will reduce your memory footprint at the expense of being slower due to the additional disk i/o operations.

In general, chunking can be trickier for bytestreams because you might end a chunk with an incomplete message (if your chunk point was arbitrary and messages were variable-width) however in your case you seem to have fixed-width messages so the chunk end-points are easier to calculate.

Either way I often find it useful to loop using over (/) and keep track of your last known (good) index and then start at that index when reading the next chunk. The general idea (untested) would be something like

```
file:`:/q/data/Q200405A.BIN;
chunkrows:10000;   /number of rows to process in each chunk
columns:`QTIM`BID`OFR`QSEQ`QFRSIZ`OFRSIZ`MODE`EX`MMID;
types:"ijjiiihcs";
widths:4 8 8 4 4 4 2 1 4;
{
    data:flip columns!(types;widths)1:(file;x;chunkrows*sum widths);
    upsertToDisk[data];      /write a function to upsert to disk (partitioned or splayed)
    x+chunkrows*sum widths        /return the rolling index of the starting point for the next chunk
    }/[hcount[file]>;0]
```

This will continue until the last good index reaches the end of the file. You can adjust the chunkrows size accordingly depending on your memory constraints.

Ultimately if you're trying to handle large-ish data with the free 32bit version then you're going to have headaches no matter what you do.